# Can I generate an appx with a windows phone project?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, xamarin.forms

My question is based on this:

I have a xamarin forms project, (which has 3 projects: iOS, Android and Windows phone). Using the build options Release ARM we have successfully generated an .xap file to upload it to the windows phone store.

My question is: Using the same project can we generate a appx file to upload it to the windows store or do we have to create a Windows Store app?

As far as I know this is not possible since I have "Create App packages" disabled:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have retarget the project to 8.1 (Windows phone silverlite) and now "Launch windows app certification kit" option is available but I cannot generate appx still.

Comment: Why do you want a `.appx` file? As far as I know those are only for `Win RT` which is dead anyway.

Comment: I wanted that type of file to upload my windows phone project to the windows store and not the windows phone store.

Comment: But it *is* a phone app right? So what use would it be to put it up on the Windows Store? They will be merged eventually anyway. I think `appx` is (also) for Universal Apps. Which means a hybrid app which works on Windows Phone as well as Windows. I don't think Xamarin supports this right now.

Comment: I wanted to be sure about that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you have completed 'Store - Create App Package..' (answer: 'No' when it asks about Store deployment),  APPX file appears in Debug/Release (NOT Package output) folder. If menu disabled - try to reload project/solution or restart VS.